# Store an string on a Shared Memory C

Tags: c, memory, shared

Hi this code is working fine storing on a shared memory integers, but i want to store strings, how can i modify it to do that?
For example the output will be Written: This is the line number 1 and in the next line Written: This is the line number 2

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void main()
{
    key_t Clave;
    int Id_Memoria;
    int *Memoria = NULL;
    int i,j;



    Clave = ftok ("/bin/ls", 33);
    if (Clave == -1)
    {
        printf("No consigo clave para memoria compartida");
        exit(0);
    }


    Id_Memoria = shmget (Clave, 1024, 0777 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (Id_Memoria == -1)
    {
        printf("No consigo Id para memoria compartida");
        exit (0);
    }


    Memoria = (int *)shmat (Id_Memoria, (char *)0, 0);
    if (Memoria == NULL)
    {
        printf("No consigo memoria compartida");
        exit (0);
    }



        for (j=0; j<100; j++)
        {
            Memoria[j] = j;
            printf( "Written: %d \n" ,Memoria[j]);
        }




    shmdt ((char *)Memoria);
    shmctl (Id_Memoria, IPC_RMID, (struct shmid_ds *)NULL);
}
```

Comment: In C a string is just a sequence of `char` elements followed by the special character `'\0'`. The difference between an "array" of integers and an "array" of characters is the size of each element, and that strings have a terminator.

Comment: the posted code does not clean compile.  For two reasons.  1) missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  2) the return type from the `main()` function is `int`, not `void`.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy string character by character to shared memory. Actual pointer pointing to the variable in shared memory needs to stay outside because shared memory can be in different addresses in different process. (You could use delta pointers but they are a lot easier in C++ [boost::offset_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html))

For manipulating strings there is string utility functions in string.h. Specially [strncpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) would be useful when moving strings to different memory locations.

Also it would be good idea to use new posix shared memory instead of your current sysv implementation. You can see more details about posix shared memory in [shm_overview](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) man page. Of course if you have an old OS that supports only sysv interface then you have to stick with old api.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem and have a hard time understanding what you exactly meant by getting a string character by character. It's kind of urgent so I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks!